# como escolher a primeira linha do retorno de um loc - PANDAS?

Tags: python, pandas

no meu exemplo abaixo:

```
RETORNO = DATAFRAME.loc[DATAFRAME['CPF'] == "000.000.000-00"]
CONTROLE = RETORNO["COLUNA_CONTROLE"]
```

a variavel CONTROLE, retorna 1 ou mais linhas (como faço pra sempre selecionar a primeira linha do retorno) ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá, você obtém apenas uma linha usando o loc novamente, da seguinte forma:

```
import pandas as pd

Table1 = {'Column1': ['50', '50', '75', '50', '10'], 'Column2': ['22', '40', '80', '20', '30'], 'Column3': ['22', '40', '80', '20', '30']}

df= pd.DataFrame(Table1, columns=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'])
result = df.loc[df['Column1'] == '50']
print(result.loc[0, 'Column2'])
```